# Find the maximum of $\frac{x}{1+yz}+\frac{y}{1+xz}+\frac{z}{1+xy}$, where $0\leq x,y,z\leq 1$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the maximum of $\frac{x}{1+yz}+\frac{y}{1+xz}+\frac{z}{1+xy}$, where $0\leq x,y,z\leq 1$. What is going on then? Trouble is the denominator. Fix $y,z$, it is not clear it is increasing/decreasing over $x$...Oh.

Comment: Is there another condition, such as $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ or $x+y+z=3$?

Comment: Check this one: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h527332p2994101